# Why composer.json file from volume directory is not visible in composer install command run in dockerfile?

Tags: php, docker, composer-php

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
    web:
        image: nginx:latest
        ports:
            - "8080:80"
        volumes:
            - ./api:/var/www/html/api
            - ./site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
        links:
            - php
    php:
        build:
            context: ./docker
            dockerfile: php.Dockerfile
        volumes:
        - ./api:/var/www/html/api
        links:
            - db
    db:
       image: mysql:5.7 
       environment:
         MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
         MYSQL_DATABASE: symfony
         MYSQL_USER: symfony
         MYSQL_PASSWORD: symfony
       ports:
         - "9906:3306"
```

php.Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7-fpm
WORKDIR /var/www/html/api
COPY --from=composer /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y \
    && apt-get install -y git libzip-dev unzip \
    && docker-php-ext-install \
        pdo_mysql zip \
    && docker-php-ext-enable \
        pdo_mysql zip \
    && composer install \
    && bin/console make:migration
```

Error from an output of command: `docker-compose build --no-cache`:

> Composer could not find a composer.json file in /var/www/html/api

However when I'm inside PHP container using `docker exec -it sf4_php_1 bash`

I see that `composer.json` file is in `/var/www/html/api` and I'm able to run `composer install` properly.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @yivi. there is an error: Service 'php' failed to build: COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder397277070/api/composer.json: no such file or directory. I think the problem is for another question, but I've no time to write it now. Anyway I'll mark your answer as correct.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The volume is mounted at **runtime**, not at **build** time.

When you are building the image, there is no `composer.json` in there because your volume has not been mounted yet.

Before you run `composer install` you will need to **copy** all the necessary files for the build process.

E.g. a better `Dockerfile` would be something like this:

(in this case I'm bringing some Symfony files, since this is copied from a Symfony image)

```
COPY --from=composer /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y \
    && apt-get install -y git libzip-dev unzip \
    && docker-php-ext-install \
        pdo_mysql zip \
    && docker-php-ext-enable \
        pdo_mysql zip

RUN mkdir -p /var/www/html/api
WORKDIR /var/www/html/api

COPY composer.json composer.lock symfony.lock .env.dist ./

RUN composer install \
    && bin/console make:migration
```

This not only will actually work, but generate different layers for the building of your application and the installation of the platform requirements. With this, changes in `composer.json` would not trigger reinstalling the PHP extensions and updating apt.